# How to enable background colors and images in browser print setup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

i am facing one issue related browser print. i want to be checked background colors and images option by default if it is unchecked by user. Is there any script in jquery/javascript to do this...

Comment: Visit [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview

property -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible, these are print settings for the user and the browser doesn't provide an API for them

The best idea is to properly provide `media=print` styling so your page looks decent when printed.