# Print preview behaves differently on Google Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have a page in bootstrap which needs to be printed. I am getting the issue on Google Chrome. There are images(vector) which needs to be printed as well.

For some reason the images which are in vector format gets Red colored background http://i60.tinypic.com/29lfp61.png. On Windows that color becomes grayish.

Also, when I am downloading the page as pdf it is not the same image that gets stored.
http://i58.tinypic.com/1fhjio.png.

Normal .jpg images work fine.

Everything works with the Mozilla.

I tried [Background color not showing in print preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview/15253634#15253634) answer from here which didn't work.

So I am not sure what exactly the issue is. Is there a fix to this? Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I see the background changes only for **image** and you try to change it for **entire table cell**. Try to use the following code for setting an image background:

```
@media print {
tr.vendorListHeading img {
   background-color: #ffffff !important;
   -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
}}
```