# Print: Background colors missing in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) in my application. The issue I am facing with it is while doing print of that calendar:

Orignal View:
http://fullcalendar.io/

[image]

On printing that page (just do CTRL+P), the colors get lost:

[image]

Has anyone else faced that issue? Is there any fix for it?

Comment: printpreview shows required color? which browser are you using ? checked any other browser?..Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview

Comment: In FF Page Setup you need to check `Print Background (colors & images)`. Other browsers have similar option. And make sure to remove `<link href="../fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">`

Answer (score 0):

If you using Bootstrap 3, the print.css file causes the issue with

```
*:after {
        // background: transparent !important; NOTE: Removed for fullcalendar printing
        color: #000 !important; // Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: And exactly what should I do to fix that issue?