# Use active class, on table. Using Bootstrap and printThis

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, printthis

I'm using Bootstrap as my framework.
To print parts of page i use "printThis" jquery plugin.

When i print a table, the active class wont show.
Active is filled row (cell).

How can i fix this?

**HTML/php**

```
if($day == "Mån"){
  $mark_monday = "active";
}

echo "<tr class='print_table_text ".$mark_monday."'>";
```

**UPDATE** CSS
I tried this, and only bold is in the print!?
I can see the "active" class added by bootstrap on webpage. But it´s not shown in the print.

```
.print_table_text {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.print_table_text.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

**PrintTHis**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#print_btn').click(function () {
        loadCSS: "css/printthis-print_all_usrs_time.css"
        $('#usr_name, #list_usr_time, #sum_worked_time, #break_page').printThis();
    });
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

I did remove the bootstrap class "active". And created an own class called grey. I used the style sheet to add background color grey. But the same problem accours. I can see the grey background in my browser, but not on the print.

```
$mark_monday = "bggrey";

.print_table_text.bggrey {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

The bold attribute is on the print, but not the BG color.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to initiate the printThis functionality.

Comment: The bold property works and displays on the print. But the "active" class, from Bootstrap who makes table row grey, aint shown on the print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this media query to your styles that will be applied for a print

```
@media print {
    td.active {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be the correct method (I am the printThis author).

Comment: @Jason Thank you. I'm not so good at CSS. But i tried this example with no success. Also i updated my question with half working css. Strange "bold" is shown, but not "background-color".

Comment: I tried changing td.active to tr.active with no succes.

Comment: @Mjukis - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview