# Table row Background Color not showing when printing

Tags: html, html-table

I am facing a problem background color in a tablerow.

```
<tr style="background-color:#999999">
        <td width="204"> <strong>Opinion</strong></td>
        <td width="62"> <strong>Action</strong></td>
        <td colspan="4"><strong>Ratings</strong></td>
        <td width="54"><strong>Outlook</strong></td>
        <td width="93"><strong>Rating Type</strong></td>
    </tr>
```

This code working fine

Here is Output

[image]

**Problem**

When I want to take print of this page. `background-color` of the row is not shown.

[image]

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Try saving as pdf first

Comment: Same problem while am print or save as pdf

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview

Answer (score 18, accepted):

add this to tr style

```
 <style>
  .row{
   background-color:#999999;
   -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
   }
 </style>

<tr class="row">
    <td width="204"> <strong>Opinion</strong></td>
    <td width="62"> <strong>Action</strong></td>
    <td colspan="4"><strong>Ratings</strong></td>
    <td width="54"><strong>Outlook</strong></td>
    <td width="93"><strong>Rating Type</strong></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: yes. i edited my answer. and its just fine. it working.

Comment: Nice answer @SaranyaR but use of inline CSS i not a good practice.

Comment: I just added that to their existing code. thank you for your information. I'll keep it in mind..

Answer (score 1):

Try using

`<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>`

structure for  table...

and use below type css..

```
@media print {
tr.vendorListHeading {
    background-color: #999999!important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
}}

@media print {
    .vendorListHeading th {
    color: white !important;
}}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can also push more settings in the print dialog and check 'Background graphics'