# @media print not working with background and colors

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have my html and I want to the colors to be applied when I do print preview or print the page. 
But the problem is, it is not working.
I also tried

```
@media print {
  tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(170, 184, 255, 0.4) !important;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust:  exact; 
 }
}

@media screen {
  tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(170, 184, 255, 0.4) !important;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust:  exact; 
 }
}
```

but it doesn't apply the colors on print preview.
I read related questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview) but it wasn't helpful.
What should I do to fix it.

For better understanding, I have the updated code in jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/8v4gn4Lu/

Comment: What browser are you using? I assume chrome?

Comment: yes, but that problem is in all browsers, like chromium, firefox