# What is the alternate for -webkit-print-color-adjust in firefox and IE

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I had some issues with the printing the background colors.

print-color-adjust made the background color issue solved in chrome.

```
body{
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

What are the **alternate CSS** in firefox and IE for this.

Comment: There are none...it's a non-standard CSS extension that can be used to force printing of background colors and images in browsers based on the **WebKit** engine.

Comment: is there any way to enforce some class to show background color in media print\

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Feb 2023 Update**: As of mid-2022 onwards, we can simply use `print-color-adjust: economy|exact` on the element, without the need to place inside a print media query.

`color-adjust` on it's own will become depreciated. (Thank you to [misterManSam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625178/what-is-the-alternate-for-webkit-print-color-adjust-in-firefox-and-ie/40723801#comment130002368_40723801) for the depreciation warning.)

**Previous answer (originally from 2016):**

As mentioned `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact` is specific to WebKit browsers, including Google's Chrome and Apple's Safari; therefore the code should work adequately in those aforementioned browsers with perhaps slightly varied results (depending on your site/app styling).

There have been proposals to standardize this snippet to work universally for not just browsers but for different devices too. The code is simplified to: `color-adjust`. Similarly to the `webkit-print-color-adjust` property, the possible values are the same for the proposed property `economy | exact`.

If you want to use the property for printing purposes, simply use within a selector inside a `@media print` query.

For example:

```
@media print {
  body { color-adjust: exact; }
}
```

I cannot guarantee the widespread adoption on browsers for the drafted property, however it is currently working on the latest version of FireFox (at the time of writing, version 50.0).

[[Source]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust)

Comment: According to caniuse it should also work on Safari browsers too. If only Microsoft would fix Edge we'd be happy...

Comment: Note that the current [draft recommendation has this value as `print-color-adjust`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-adjust-1/#propdef-print-color-adjust) and `color-adjust` is deprecated.

Comment: Why is `color-adjust` used in the latest Bootstrap release (5.3.0) https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css - line 2405?

Answer (score 22):

There is the alternate CSS to print background colors for Chrome And Firefox.

```
td { 
 -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;//:For Chrome
  color-adjust: exact;//:For Firefox
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. After trying to solve this one, `color-adjust: exact;` works for firefox while the webkit does not.

Answer (score 10):

This is beginning to work in Firefox (at least version 48.0.2) with the "color-adjust" property.

```
td { 
  background: #000 !important;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  color-adjust: exact;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/print-color-adjust#browser_compatibility

1. Firefox accepts `print-color-adjust` and `color-adjust`;
2. Safari accepts `print-color-adjust` and `-webkit-print-color-adjust` (edit: https://caniuse.com/?search=print-color-adjust says it only supports `-webkit-` version; if anyone actually using Safari can settle this, I'll edit);
3. Chrome and Edge accept `-webkit-print-color-adjust`.

Comment: For Safari, as is true with most others except Firefox: `Implemented with the vendor prefix: -webkit-`. How do you know Safari accepts `print-color-adjust`?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ The sentence you quote applies to Safari 6; 15.4 has "Full support" and no `-X-` meaning "Requires a vendor prefix or different name for use". Similarly for Firefox, 48 has "Alternate name: color-adjust" and 97 has "Full support".

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Though I see the first chart in https://caniuse.com/?search=print-color-adjust disagrees, so I edited the answer.