# Command for exporting/saving table made with Formattable package in R

Tags: r, save, export, formattable

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/formattable.pdf

I've been using the Formattable package to make some nice looking tables in R. I'm trying to save the tables as images (or really any file format) but can't find a command that works. Using the jpeg/png function or dev.copy creates blank documents. Ideally I'd like to be able to save these tables in a loop. Does anyone know how this might be done?

data:

```
library(formattable)
DF <- data.frame(Ticker=c("", "", "", "IBM", "AAPL", "MSFT"),
                 Name=c("Dow Jones", "S&P 500", "Technology", 
                        "IBM", "Apple", "Microsoft"),
                 Value=accounting(c(15988.08, 1880.33, NA, 
                                    130.00, 97.05, 50.99)),
                 Change=percent(c(-0.0239, -0.0216, 0.021, 
                                  -0.0219, -0.0248, -0.0399)))

formattable(DF, list(
  Name=formatter(
    "span",
    style = x ~ ifelse(x == "Technology", 
                       style(font.weight = "bold"), NA)),
  Value = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  Change = formatter(
    "span",
    style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0 , "red", "green")),
    x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), x)))
)
```

Comment: This looks pretty much like a tool request, bound to get closed. You could avoid it by adding a small reproducible example (data and code) which you want to "imagify".

Answer (score 18):

To save you formattable you can use 'as.htmlwidget' and then printscreen it.
First run the next function:

```
library("htmltools")
library("webshot")    

export_formattable <- function(f, file, width = "100%", height = NULL, 
                               background = "white", delay = 0.2)
    {
      w <- as.htmlwidget(f, width = width, height = height)
      path <- html_print(w, background = background, viewer = NULL)
      url <- paste0("file:///", gsub("\\\\", "/", normalizePath(path)))
      webshot(url,
              file = file,
              selector = ".formattable_widget",
              delay = delay)
    }
```

(source: https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable/issues/26)

Then in your code assing the formattable to a variable and use the function to save it.

```
FT <- formattable(DF, list(
  Name=formatter("span", 
                 style = x ~ ifelse(x == "Technology", style(font.weight = "bold"), NA)), 
  Value = color_tile("white", "orange"), 
  Change = formatter("span", 
                     style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0 , "red", "green")), 
                     x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), x))) )

export_formattable(FT,"FT.png")
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, if `value` is `0`, which icon should we use? How to add it in your code?

Comment: May I ask how to adjust the width and height ratio of output image?

Comment: this works well for me. Old thread, so the probability of a reply is low, I think , but how can I make the png high resolution, e.g., 300dpi?

Comment: @MathewVickers the `webshot` function has an argument `zoom` where "A zoom factor of 2 will result in twice as many pixels vertically and horizontally. "