# Export table created in formattable in R

Tags: r

I am plotting a table like below. Is there a way to save it? I can't just export it as it only exports the partial image.

```
test1 %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise("Weekly_trend" = spk_chr(Total))  %>%
  left_join(data) %>%
  formattable() %>%
  as.datatable() %>%
  spk_add_deps()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command for exporting/saving table made with Formattable package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833219/command-for-exporting-saving-table-made-with-formattable-package-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I answered your last question I have a bit more background. For some reason, the table you made doesn't seem to want to export with the method mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833219/command-for-exporting-saving-table-made-with-formattable-package-in-r).

However, you can export the table and save it as an image using the following code. First, the table gets saved as an htmlwidget. You can open the output `.html` file that gets output and see the table if you wanted to. `webshot` will then take a picture of the table and save it as an image.

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(webshot)

test1 %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise("Weekly_trend" = spk_chr(Total)) %>%
  formattable() %>%
  as.datatable(options = list(pageLength = 30)) %>%
  spk_add_deps() -> w

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(w, "table.html", selfcontained = TRUE)

webshot::webshot(url = "table.html", file = "table.png", 
                 vwidth = 1000, vheight = 275)
```