# How can we force a printer to include the th and td color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap.min.css and for some reason the background color for "th"  is ignored while printing. Is there a way, i can force the color to be printed. I have tried adding the media style to the page, but that is still not creating the background while printing.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">  
         <table class="table" bordercolor="FFFFFF">
            <thead>
              <tr >
                <th 
                style="background-color:ec6619;">


                 <font color="FFFFFF">Label</font></th>
              </tr>


            </thead>

          </table>
        </div>



        <div class="col-xs-6" >
        <table class="table" bordercolor="FFFFFF">
        <thead>
              <tr >
                <th style="color:000; 
                           font-weight:normal; 
                           font-size: 18px;  
                           font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">

                  #someotherlabel#

               </th>
              </tr>


        </thead>

        </table>    

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your inline CSS is wrong, the `th` won't have have a background color at all the way it's currently coded, you need to put a `#` in front of the hex code.

Comment: This might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview

Comment: @JqueryHelp you must insert a   `td ` or  `div` or anything else in your  `th` set  `background-color ` for him or anything else for that element , not for  `th ` , because it does not support some CSS properties

Comment: thank you for the link rubentd, there was an exact example I was looking for. However now thead element is ignoring the background color. this is what gor the th to display the color while printing th.fornewone
     {
      background-color: #ec6619 !important;
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
     }

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will not print background colors.

There is usually a checkbox in the Print or Page Setup dialog to enable this.

Comment: Slaks, I have tried what you have suugested , i.e. having the  background images and colors, but to no avail.