# angularjs wanted print layout wont be correct

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im currently using this:

```
<li ng-repeat="items in ferdigheter">{{ items.title}}
<div class="circles">
    <div class="circle" ng-repeat="a in thisnumber(items.stars)"></div>
    <div class="empty_circle" ng-repeat="a in thisnumber(items.maxstars - items.stars)"></div>

</div>
</li>
```

When im viewing whats beeing printed (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) the title  is there, but the circles / empty circle is not ther in the print. any idea why?

How can i make sure that the circle`s will be printed too?

current page:

[image]

current print:

[image]

wanted print:

[image]

update:

scope:

```
  $scope.ferdigheter = [
        {tittel: 'Adobe Photoshop', stars: 2, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'CSS/html', stars: 5, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'PHP', stars: 4, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'Angular', stars: 3, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'Javascript', stars: 4, maxstars:5},
        {tittel: 'MS Word', stars: 4, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'Dreamviewer', stars: 2, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'Phpstorm', stars: 4, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'Codeigniter', stars: 5, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'XXX', stars: 3, maxstars: 5},
        {tittel: 'XXX', stars: 5, maxstars: 5},

    ];
```

Scope `thisnumber` Creates an array

Comment: this seems like an issue with CSS, not an issue with angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

CSS styles for printing can be tricky. In Chrome for example you might need to use **-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;** for yours to work.

See a much more complete answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15253634/55154

Comment: It's very easy to try by adding that attribute to you circle class in your stylesheet. It should work in Chrome if you are styling your circles by using a background color for example.

Comment: What about ie ?

Comment: No way of doing it like this in IE. There seems to be workarounds, like using very thick borders instead of backgrounds and such, but as I said it gets tricky, and this is were my knowledge on the subject ends. Sorry.