# Bootstrap Print Overrides CSS

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, colors

As already discussed here:
[Background color not showing in print preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview)

I haven't figured out yet, how to get my actual text coloring. I want to get a div only shown on print with the Bootstrap class print-visible, works fine but all the coloring is lost in the preview.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s671v12g/2/)

```
@media print {
  .test {
    background-color: #1a4567 !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
  }
}
```

If I add the media print CSS it does what it should, but I want the text-colors not the color set by CSS.

Comment: Are your printer settings set to allow background colors and images to be printed?

Comment: Yes. If i remove the bootstrap-cdn from the jsFiddle, it gets printed with text colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited** based on comment:

You can add `!important` using JavaScript's `style.setProperty()` method in 2 ways:

1. **Pure JS:** `document.getElementById()`.
2. **jQuery hybrid:** Wrap it inside jQuery's `.each()` .

Both examples below:

```js
$('#filePrintPreview').html("TEST");
//way 1: pure JS exmple
document.getElementById('filePrintPreview').style.setProperty('color', 'red', 'important');
//way 2: wrapped inside jQuery's each() example
$('h3').each(function() {
  this.style.setProperty('color', '#12FF12', 'important');
});
```

```css
@media print {
  .test {
    background-color: #1a4567 !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 test">
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <div class="box no-border shadow" id="filePrintPreview" style="padding: 2px; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-line;">
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-flat btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-top:15px;" onclick=" window.print();">Print
</button>
```

Comment: In my case the !important way works, obviously. But thats not exactly what i need. I have the user to choose a color for the printed text. Can i set the !important tag via jQuery?

Comment: DrDreo, yes you can but with JS though, edited above, hope helps. Regards.

Comment: I have never thought of setting the color !import in that way. Thank you very much. Although setting !important is a pain, i only need one division be printed in color. This is exactly how it works.