# print preview class get different view from normal view

Tags: css

hi i have css class called bg-gray
and this is the code

```
.bg-gray{
    background-color:#6C7A89 !important;
    color:#ffffff  !important;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    border:#000000 1px solid;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; 
}
```

in normal view its look like this
[image]
but in print preview its look like this
[image]
as you can see the background turned to white and the color for text turned for white
also i tried to put this in my css file

```
@media print{
.bg-gray{
    background-color:#6C7A89 !important;
  }
}
```

also gat same result there is no background color for class bg-gray
thanks

Comment: Maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview

Comment: give us more details.. there's nothing wrong in the code above, but it may be something related to browser