# background color disappears when printing using window.print()

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

i'm trying to print a page in angulat , using `window.print();` , everything works fine, all other css works fine, the only matter is that the background color is not displaying in the printable documents, i've attached a StackBlitz exemple, so : has anyone encountered this problem before ? , if yes what is the solution , Thanks.

[StackBlitz Exemple from here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-printing-solution-secx9l)

**Note :** I did a lot of research on stackoverflow and other forumes , and no one is talking about this problem.

**Printable File HTML :**

```
<div class="page-container">
<div class="title-container">Invoice Title</div>
<div class="body-container">
  This is what I'm going to print, everything works fine , but the background color never changes , no matter what i add to css file
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS of the page :**

```
.page-container{
  width: 100%;
  background-color : rgb(216, 23, 23);  // as you can see , background not working 
}
.title-container{
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px blueviolet solid;
  color: rgb(228, 0, 228);
  background-color : rgb(221, 0, 0) !important;// not working also
}
.body-container{
  background : #000; // not working 
}
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: Your printer is set up to save ink and not print backgrounds.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=print+background+color

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` to css page solved the problem in chrom , and `color-adjust: exact;` to solve the problem in mozilla firefox !