# Is it possible to make Window.Print() method to print the highlighted text with its background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As we can verify by copying/pasting the following `html` on the following w3schools.com [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_print) that it highlights the word `highlighted` with `yellow background`, and the word `test` with `red foreground`. But, as shown in the image below, when you print this html page with `Window.Print()` command, it does not print the yellow background of the word `highlighted`. **Question**: Is there a workaround to make `Window.Print()` method work for highlighted text, as well?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>The window.print() Method</h2>

<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>
<p>This is a <span style='background:yellow;'> highlighted</span> text. And <span style='color:red;'>test</span> for font color.</p>

<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**snapshot  in Windows 10  of `Print to PDF` preview of the above html**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background color not showing in print preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview)

Comment: I think you might need to enable "print backgrounds" under "more settings" in the print dialog.

Comment: @Emaro Your suggestion worked (thank you for sharing your thoughts). Under `More Settings`, on my Windows 10 built-in printer preview, there are two options `Headers and Footers`, and `Background Graphics`. The Background Graphics option is unchecked by default. When I checked it - Voila - it started showing highlights correctly in both print preview and in actual print.

Comment: Glad it worked! :)