# Rows color on report doesn't show up on print out/preview

Tags: php, html, colors, report

so, we are trying to give color to rows on our report. but the color doesn't added to the print preview.

here is the report result
[image: report result]

and this is the print out preview
[image]

and this the code

```
while ($bayar = mysqli_fetch_array ($querybayar)){
                        if($bayar['Status_Lunas']=="Lunas"){
                            echo "
                            <tr>
                                <td>$no</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Nama_Mahasiswa] <br>($bayar[NIM])</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Kode_Kelas_Mhs] / $bayar[Semester_Lunas]</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Angsuran1]</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Tanggal_Angsuran]</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Angsuran2]</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Tanggal_Lunas]</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Total]</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Status_Lunas]</td>
                            </tr>";
                            $no++;
                        } else {
                            echo "
                            <tr style='background-color: orange;'>
                                <td>$no</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Nama_Mahasiswa] <br>($bayar[NIM])</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Kode_Kelas_Mhs] / $bayar[Semester_Lunas]</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Angsuran1]</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Tanggal_Angsuran]</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Angsuran2]</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Tanggal_Lunas]</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Total]</td>
                                <td>$bayar[Status_Lunas]</td>
                            </tr></p>";
                            $no++;
```

any kind of help is much appreciated, Thank you

the problem is solved here
[Background color not showing in print preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview)

thank you

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview is the answer.

Comment: holy... thank you. it doesn't show when i'm typing the title
@NigelRen should i delete this post, or just leave it be?