# I can't get any elements to display color in print preview

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

I'm using angular 4 and need a user to be able to print a section of data. I can get a print preview with bootstrap working just fine, however, no color shows up whatsoever when I show the preview. I've gotten this same result in chrome and safari, and even with the background colors checked on in safari, the colors still don't show up.

[image: Screenshot]

The left side of the screenshot is what color is supposed to show up, the right is what the print preview shows.

I also found that the same thing happens with just the regular application itself when I right click and select print. Other websites show up totally fine with color in print preview.

[image: Screenshot]

This is my print function (which right now is pretty much pulled from another stack overflow question, I plan on changing this later.)

```
print(): void {
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <title>Print tab</title>
          <style>
            .lightBlue {
              background-color: lightblue !important;
            }

            @media print {
              .lightBlue {
                background-color: lightblue !important;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
              }
            }
          </style>
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
  }
```

This is the HTML is being displayed in the print window:

```
<div id="print-section" [hidden]="printable">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Location Report for {{showOnly}}s</h1>
    <br/>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead class="lightBlue">
        <tr>
          <th >Dog</th>
          <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried so many solutions on stack overflow and I haven't got any of them to work, so I'm kind of at a loss at this point.

Comment: Are you sure it's not simply a matter of the browser settings for printing background colours? The screenshot to the "regular application itself" does have colours, just no background colours.

Comment: True, I get the same result in Safari however, even with the background colors box checked. That bar in the printable is literally the only thing I need to have color, everything else is black and white. If I could somehow trick that element into having color, that would work for me.

Comment: is there any way to bring `.scss` file into picture before printing the doc?

Comment: [this could be the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553439/div-background-color-in-print-page-doesnt-work), try enabling `print background` option in the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [div background color in print page doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553439/div-background-color-in-print-page-doesnt-work)

Comment: I've tried print background color in both safari and firefox (chrome doesn't have it) and I still get the same result. The only difference is now some borders will show up in color when I turn it on, but everything largely remains the same. I also tried using the box shadow trick, but strangely enough only works when I take out the inset, which then colors the entire page and not the div I want colored.

Comment: Ok I think there is just something straight up wrong with my project. My global stylesheet isn't working either. I ported this project from another project, and I'm thinking something went wrong along the way. I just generated a new angular project and color printing works totally fine in the new project. I'm gonna migrate this project over to a new one file by file and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, I figured it out. Bootstrap was causing the colors not to show up. It also was causing my global css file to not work. Using bootstrap 4 instead of 3 seems to have solved the second issue, however the printing issue still exists. So I'm just not gonna use bootstrap for files that I need to print.